# getting attribute a tag when keyup is on input it

Tags: javascript, attributes, jquery, attr

how can getting attribute class in 'class="auto_box" -> tag b', when .keyup() is on each of input it?

if keyup is on '.search hotel input' give me classe search hotel.
if keyup is on '.guide_search input' give me classe guide_search.

html

```
<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="search_hotel">
    <span></span>    
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" style="border: none; float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" name="search_hotel" placeholder="هتل" title="هتل" /></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_hotel"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="guide_search">
    <span></span>
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" style="border: none; float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" name="guide_search" placeholder="راهنما" title="ارلاین"></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_guide"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
        var specific = '.' + $('.auto_box b').attr('class');
});
```

this js only getting attribute class search_hotel and not getting attribute class guide_search, when is keyup on input it.

Comment: `$('.auto_box b')` searches for all elements that match this selector. `.attr('class')` will give you the class of the first element of this set. You have to make your selector *relative* to the input field that has the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're looking for is:

```
$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
        var specific = '.' + $(this).closest('div.auto_box').find('b').attr('class');
});
```

Now, one thing you should know is that nesting `<div>` elements inside `<b>` is invalid markup; a `<b>` element is supposed to contain only inline content, and not block-level elements like `<div>` or `<ul>`.

Comment: i want getting class of tag '.auto_box b' no .auto_complete.